# Sorting Excel Rows & Columns into descending order of activity

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I have a spreadsheet with 45 rows and 85 columns. Not all 85 columns contain information. Some rows will fill all 85 columns, some rows only fill 40 or 50 columns. Is it possible to sort the spreadsheet so that the row with the most filled columns is at the top, then descending until the row with the fewest columns filled is at the bottom?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a column that performs a count of non-blank cells in each row. Then sort on that column in descending order. For example, in cell "CI1" the formula for the previous 85 cells in that row would be:

```
=COUNTA(A1:CH1)
```

Fill the formulas down over all rows, and you'll have a count of populated cells for each row. Then, just sort on column "CI" in descending order.